# Does this matrix equation always have a solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvector, matrix-equations

Let $\{A_i, i\ge 3\}$ be the matrices whose columns represent numbers from $0$ to $2^i-1$ in binary form. For example,

$A_3 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ % 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$

$A_4 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$

I am interested in vectors $x$ such that $Ax = \vec{0}$, with the additional constraint that half of the values in $x$ are $-1$ and the other half is $1$. For example,

$x_a=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}^T$ and

$x_b=\begin{bmatrix}1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}^T$ are two possible solutions for $A_3x=\vec{0}$.

Observe that the set of solution is always non-empty. For example, $x_a$ could be generalized for any $i\ge 3$, with half of the $1$'s at the beginning, half of them in the end, and all $-1$'s in the middle.

I want to understand whether solutions are still guaranteed when additional rows are added $A_i$ as follows:

- $2^{i-1}$ extra rows are added,
- Each of them has only two 1's (0 elsewhere),
- One of these 1's is in the first half of the columns, the other is in the other half,
- Each column receives only one $1$ over these rows

Apart from these restrictions, the extra rows could be any.

For example,

$A_3'= \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\\hline  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$

My question is the following:

- **Does $A_i'x=\vec{0},$ with $i \ge 3$, always have a solution?**

Based on experiments, this seems plausible, although I can't find a clear argument as to why this should be true.

Comment: Your matrices $A_i$ come up as generator matrices for Hamming codes (except those don't have an all-zero column).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Here is an explicit counter-example for the $i = 3$ case:

$$
A_3^\prime = \begin{bmatrix}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The null space of this matrix is the span of the vector $(1,0,-1,0,0,-1,0,1)$, so there is no solution to $A_3^\prime x = \vec{0}$ having each entry equal to $\pm 1$, let alone with half of the entries equal to $+1$ and half equal to $-1$.

Comment: Good catch. Interestingly, this configuration never shows up in my use cases (where all the A'3 and A'4 that I actually get do admit a solution). This means there must be additional conditions on the extra-rows, which I haven't identified yet (these constraints come themselves from a complicated process). If I may, I'd like to think a bit more before we settle this question, to get a chance to add these constraints here. In the meantime, do you see any (if possible, not too trivial) restriction that may guarantee a solution, for some algebraic reasons?